# Why matrix.shift() is almost 25x faster than indexing in this javascript code

Tags: javascript

I noticed this behaviour while solving this leetcode problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/description/

Here is the code:

```
function searchMatrix(matrix, target) {
    const len = matrix.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //const row = matrix.shift();  // if i access row using matrix.shift() the code executes in less than 100 ms. 
        const row = matrix[i]   // But if i access the row via indexing.  then it takes more than 2000ms and sometimes even gives Time limit exceeded.
        let start = 0, end = row.length - 1;

        while (start <= end) {
            const mid = start + Math.floor((end - start) / 2);

            if (row[mid] === target) return true;

            if (row[mid] < target) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In this code if i access row using `const row = matrix.shift();` the code executes in less than 100 ms.
but if i access the row via indexing using `const row = matrix[i]` .  then it takes more than 2000ms and sometimes even gives Time limit exceeded.

Please help me understand why there is such a huge performance difference.

I checked Ecma script specifications here:
https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.shift
and for shift() , internally java script also uses a while loop with indexing so it should take O(n) time for each row and it should be slower than indexing.

i Tried ChatGpt and Gemini and got some info. But it dint cite any reference so it might be making things up or hallucinating. here is the answer Gemini gave:

> "Here are key factors contributing to shift()'s efficiency:
>
> Built-in Optimizations: JavaScript engines are heavily optimized for common array operations like shift(). They often implement them using low-level code that's significantly faster than plain JavaScript loops. These optimizations can include:
>
> In-Place Shifting: Manipulating internal pointers to elements within the same memory block, minimizing data movement and avoiding unnecessary memory reallocations.
> Cache-Friendly Rearrangement: Reordering elements in a way that maximizes cache utilization, leading to faster access times for subsequent operations.
> Hidden Overheads in for Loops: While for loops appear simpler, they can involve subtle overheads that shift() often avoids:
>
> Variable Lookups: Each iteration of a for loop requires looking up loop variables and condition values, adding some overhead.
> Bounds Checks: Loops often involve explicit bounds checks to ensure array access is within valid limits, potentially incurring additional costs.
> Potentially Less Efficient Rearrangement: Manually rearranging elements in a for loop might not always be as cache-friendly as the optimized implementations used for shift().
> Additional Considerations:
>
> Array Size: The performance difference between shift() and indexing can become more pronounced with larger arrays, as shift()'s optimizations become more beneficial for larger data sets.
> Data Types: The specific data types stored in the array can also influence performance, as optimizations might be tailored for certain types (e.g., numbers)."

Comment: what datatype, size and format of your `matrix`? could you provide it in JS to test?

Comment: I do not see that behavior, which makes sense.

Comment: Pull the code out of the website and test it yourself with your own test data.

Comment: `matrix.shift()` modifies the array. If you call the function twice, the second time it will be processing an empty array, which of course will be fast.

Comment: The optimizations they're talking about make the built-in operation faster than implementing it yourself. But it can't make it faster than not modifying the array at all.

Comment: Figure out which row x might be in first, by comparing it to the first element of each row.